# LAN wire is not detecting in ubuntu 12.04 Lts

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04, wired-networking

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Windows 7. After that, the Internet is working in Windows 7 via ethernet, but in Ubuntu 12.04, ethernet is not working. It is showing me the message `WIRED NETWORK Disconnected-you are offline now`. **Why this problem is coming and how to solve this?**

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! To get a better response, you should also mention any steps you have taken to try to fix this yourself

Comment: When do you see this message? What is showing it to you? (Some specific program?) And when you see it, is the wired network actually disconnected? (What does `ipconfig` say?)